# curl: (77) pbm with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, repository, ssl

I am in root in my directory on CentOS release 6.6 and I want to do the following in order to install mysql in upper version on centOS:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

After that I have the following error:

```
Retrieving https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
error: skipping https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm - transfer failed
```

This is my `uname -a`:

```
Linux hosting 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 01:55:02 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## Update

This is my base repo:

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does [this StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064601/curl-not-working-error-77-for-ssl-connections-on-centos-for-non-root-users) question help?

Comment: This is different

Comment: The link in Will's answer seems very similar to your situation.  Did you try that?

Comment: @garethTheRed Yes I did...Not working

Answer (score 5):

You could try to reinstall the `ca-certificates` bundle and the `openssl` package on your server:

```
$ sudo yum reinstall ca-certificates openssl
```

Comment: I have the error: `Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
`

Comment: Hmm, are you able to communicate with `mirror.centos.org`, try testing with: `telnet mirror.centos.org 80`. How does your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file look like?

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: I'd suggest you to uncomment the `baseurl` variable and try again.

Comment: So now: `Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again`

Comment: and `Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (on a CentOS 6 machine):

```
mkdir /usr/src/ca-certificates && cd /usr/src/ca-certificates

wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7.noarch.rpm

rpm2cpio ca-certificates-2015.2.6-65.0.1.el6_7.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv

cp -pi ./etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.* /etc/pki/tls/certs/
```

Answer yes to overwrite the files.

To check:

```
curl -vvv https://www.unixy.net
```